# GCP API for getting list of labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there an GCP API for getting labels for resources?
I want to get a list of all labels for GCP Project. How to get all labels in GCP?
Basically GCP Resource Manager API return the Lebel object for every resource.
But I want to get list of all labels using one API call.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the next workaround to get all the labels:

```
gcloud projects describe <YOUR-PROJECT-NAME> --format=json | jq -r '.labels|to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]'
```

You will receive a key=value list.

Comment: Amazing solution. You just need to install `jq` tool beforehand and it works perfectly. Thanks @Bumeranghc

Comment: This will only return labels that are available in GCP Resource Manager, it will not return any that are assigned to instances, etc.

Comment: You could use it listing too for all the resources you want. like: 
`gcloud projects list --format=json | jq -r '.[].labels'`
This way is faster and folder wide

Answer (score 2):

You could list for all the resources you want and filter what you need as @Bumeranghc said with the proper --format like (with jq for further manipulation): `gcloud projects list --format=json | jq -r '.[].labels'`

Without jq: `gcloud projects list —-format=“json(projectId, labels)”`

Comment: You can use this to have the name AND the labels:

`gcloud projects list --format=json | jq -r '.[] | "\(.name) \(.labels|tostring)`

Comment: There is a “native” way to do that without jq, I edited my answer with that. I hope it helps @RaffaeleCastagno

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to list all labels within a GCP project.

Beside what you mention about `GCP Resource Manager API`, you could get some information from [Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview), however it won't fulfill your requirements.

To achieve what you want, you can fill a `Feature Request` in GCP [IssueTracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to create this possibility.