# How to list GCP project labels in Cloud function?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

Below documentation has details for accessing various GCP resources but not GCP project. I am interested in listing all the labels of a GCP project using .net API.

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference

Any references/links will be helpful

Comment: What you're looking for is the `Resource Manager` libs/API https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
        Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3.ProjectsClient projectsClient = await Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3.ProjectsClient.CreateAsync();
        Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3.Project response = await projectsClient.GetProjectAsync("projects/83446985491");
        //response.Labels;
```

Source:
https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3/latest/Google.Cloud.ResourceManager.V3.Projects.ProjectsClient

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71437585/10190802), Currently, it's not possible to list all labels within a **GCP project**.

In Addition, There is an existing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/208675424), you can **star** this feature request and add `Me too` in the thread. This will bring more attention to the request as more users request support for it but there's no guarantee when it will be implemented.